# Drawing an arc in ios

Tags: ios

I have a requirement to display like in the attached image. i am able to draw circle. but the remaining or not getting how to. If any one have idea please let me know.[image]

Comment: [these open source code may help you](http://code4app.net/category/progress)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `-[UIBezierPath addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:]`. That method does just what the name says -- it adds an arc to the path with a given radius, center, and start and end angles.